# UIPageControl using Interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder, uipagecontrol

I succeeded in implementing a horizontal scroll using UIPageControl + UIScrollView using code.
But the views in my pages are slightly more involved and need fine grain control. So I am trying to design the views using Interface Builder.

All examples for UIpagecontrol & uiscrollview seem to use code to generate the views.

1) But can anyone point me to an example which uses IB to design the views and then manage scrolling in code? I need to support ios4 - so no storyboards.

2) If you advise against this approach due to memory concerns, can you please suggest an alternative approach which maintains a similar effect?

I use a navigation based project.

Comment: IB is just a substitute for alloc and all properties relate to displaying the actual control.  Just delete your now boiler-plate code and hook up those outlets.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks for the response. The current code I have is pretty basic one (swaps out different UIImageViews based on page number) - I need IB to develop the more complex views.